# Does Android native sip stack support video over sip?

Tags: android, sip

I have implemented successfully sip audio call using android native sip stack. But some how i dont see any information regardind video call over sip using android native sip stack. May be they do not support sip over rtp? . Any information would be highly appreciated. i coudlnt find any clear information on stackoverflow regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android native sip stack has a very limited feature and i wont recommend to any one. It does not support video feature by default. For video feature it will require bidirectional information flow ,which require RTP. So in short answer no. Better try other opensource sip like pjsip.